# Verifying elements in for loop using Browser Robot Framework

Tags: browser, robotframework

I'm trying to verify elements state with the same data selectors in loop. There are multiple images with the same data selector value.

```
*** Variables ***
${CARD_IMAGE}    //*[@data-selector="image"]

*** Keywords ***
@{IMAGES}   Get Elements    ${CARD_IMAGE}

Loop
    FOR  ${OBJECT}  IN  @{IMAGES}
        Wait For Elements State  ${OBJECT}  visible
    END
```

But I'm having:

> elementHandle.waitForSelector: selector: expected string, got object

Is there any way to verify elements in such conditions?

Comment: Please provide more information to make the issue reproducible - What are the libraries you are using, what kind of content is expected to be returned from the ``Get Elements`` keyword and what is the actual output you are receiving from it.

Comment: The library is Browser, uses playwright, `Get Elements` returns webelement objects, while the `Wait For Elements State` expects a string - a locator, that it will find the element for by itself. Thus the error - it cannot deal with webelements. You should probably file this as a bug to the library - in SeleniumLibrary for example this works as pretty much any method can work with either a locator, or already found webelement.

Comment: As an intermediate solution, you might try to count how many elements match the locator, get a loop and pass a slightly different locator which is "the n-th element that matches the overall locator" - e.g. in xpath that would be `(//locator)[n]`

Comment: Thanks @TodorMinakov, that's exactly the solution I'm trying to code but I was curious if the problem can be solved in easier way. Thanks!